# How can I backup the state in my Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I’m planning to use Azure Logic App to schedule ad hoc jobs from my app at runtime. My Logic App Will then become a database of custom scheduled jobs. Like any database, I want to make sure the state is backed up in case of a disaster or accidental deletion.

I’ve not discovered a way to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: Blob storage?  SQL DB?  You have to do this yourself.  They're stateless applications.  As for "accidental deletion", you should lock it so that can't happen and "in case of disaster", you use these services with the peace of mind that Microsoft won't let that happen but having said that, they're stateless anyway so a disaster will only affect your app definition really and that can be backed up in git.

Comment: You say they’re stateless, but unless I’ve misunderstood there is state in the form of ad hoc schedules. Are you suggesting I duplicate that state somewhere and if I had to restore all those scheduled jobs I’d need to write a bespoke tool to read from my duplicated schedule and place them back in the Logic app?

Comment: If I’m not understanding then can you provide more information to help me understand? I still don’t see anything you’re doing is considered as stateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### WAY-1

One of the workarounds that you can try is to navigate to your **Resource Group >> Activity log >> Deleted Workflow >> Change history(Preview) >> < deleted resource>**.

[image]

From there you can copy the old JSON schema to your new logic app code view in its format.

[image]

[image]

My new logic app

[image]

#### WAY - 2

Instead of building it right away in the portal, you can use Visual Studio to construct Logic apps and commit them to Azure DevOps. This allows you to build and test locally before deploying.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Recovering a deleted Logic App with Azure Portal](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/recovering-deleted-logic-app-azure-portal-pedro-almeida)
2. [Edit and manage logic apps using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/manage-logic-apps-with-visual-studio)